# PHP parsing Text area from textfile

Tags: php, parsing, text-files

I've got a textfile with the following structure:

```
[account]
user                          = heinz
pwd                           = heinz123
description                   = ralf
caid                          = 098C,1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0648,0500,0B02,09C4
expdate                       = 2015-06-30
au                            = 1
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30
cccmaxhops                    = 5
cccreshare                    = 0
cccignorereshare              = 1

[account]
user                          = klaus
pwd                           = klaus123
caid                          = 098C,1702,1830,0B00,0648,0D95,0500,09C4
description                   = sven
au                            = 1
betatunnel                    = 1833.FFFF:1702
expdate                       = 2015-06-30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30
services                      = !xxl
cccmaxhops                    = 5
cccreshare                    = 1
cccignorereshare              = 1

[account]
user                          = paul
pwd                           = paul123
description                   = ralf
caid                          = 1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0648,0500,0B02,098C
betatunnel                    = 1833.FFFF:1702
expdate                       = 2015-06-30
group                         = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30
cccmaxhops                    = 5
cccreshare                    = 0
cccignorereshare              = 1
```

Now for example I need to get the "user" field where the description is "sven". This should return "klaus". Any idea how to get this done easy using PHP? Each user block starts with "[account]" and ends with "cccignorereshare              = 1".

Comment: Split on `[account]`, split on `=`, create an array. It should be easy then. That's all I'll say now since you haven't shown what you've tried so far.

Comment: Seems almost like an ini file to me.

Comment: I read about .ini Files and parsing them in PHP, I think using parse_ini_file

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your file-contents are loaded inside the var `$content`. This will do the job and point you in the right direction to get other informations from the content-string/file.

```
// Build array
$accounts = array();
$tmpAccounts = explode( "[account]", $content );
foreach ( $tmpAccounts as $data ) {
    $tmpLines = explode( "\n", $data );
    $parsedData = array();
    foreach ( $tmpLines as $line ) {
        list( $key, $value ) = explode( "=", $line );
        $parsedData[trim( $key )] = trim( $value );
    }
    $accounts[] = $parsedData;
}

// Find 'sven' as description in array
$user = '';
foreach ( $accounts as $account ) {
    if ( $account['description'] == 'sven' ) {
        $user = $account['user'];
    }
}

// Output
echo( $user );
```

Another way is to use some kind of regular-expressions. But the above code should do the work.